# Dojo Javascript Filteringselect Box Empty after Selection

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a problem displaying the values that should be displayed within the box 'SelectType'. When the page loads, thers no selection made as desired. The dropdown will open as desired and the desired values will appear.
However, if you choose a value, it does not stay in the box and I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" in the output of the debugger.
Unfortunately, I'm quite new to the Dojo Framework and Javascript and puzzle for days on a solution. Does anyone have an idea or a tip for me? Enclosed the code: If something is missing, then let me know.

Thanks in advance

```
            startup: function() {

            if(this.logger.isDebug()) {
                this.logger.debug("startup()");
            }

            try {
                this.borderContainer.startup();
            } catch(ex) {
                console.dir(ex);
            }

            this.selectUser.set('store', new JsonRestStore({
                    service:        RestService.create({ path: 'servicelog/users/'}),
                    idAttribute:    "userId"
                })
            );
            this.selectUser.set('searchAttr', "userId");

            this.selectType.set('store', new JsonRestStore({
                    service:        RestService.create({ path: 'servicelog/methods/'}),
                    idAttribute:    "nr"
                })
            );          

            this.selectType.set('labelFunc', lang.hitch(this, function(item, store) { 
                return this.resources.getString('servicelog.type.' + item.nr, store);
            }));

            this.selectionFetch = {};

            if (this.restore) {
                this.setOptions(this.restore);
            } else {
                this.selectType.set('item', { nr : 0 });
                this.selectFrom.set('value', new Date());
            }

            this.store = new JsonRestStore({
                service: RestService.create({
                            path: 'servicelog/find/'
                        }),
                idAttributes: ["logId"],
                fetchProperties : this.selectionFetch
            });

            this.grid.set('structure', this.prepareColumnStructure());
            this.grid.set('formatterScope', this);
            this.grid.set('store', this.store);

            /* Listener */
            on(this.grid, "RowDblClick", lang.hitch(this, this.onDblClick));
            on(this.buttonReload, "Click", lang.hitch(this, this.refresh));
            on(this.buttonExport, "Click", lang.hitch(this, this.exportData));

            this.onLoad();
            this.setSearchAttributes();

            if(this.logger.isDebug()) {
                this.logger.debug("startup(...)  [grid: ", this.grid, ", store: ", this.store, "]");
            }
        },

        setSearchAttributes : function() {
            this.selectionFetch = {};

            //SELECT TYPE
            if (this.selectType.getValue() > 0) {
                this.selectionFetch.selectType = this.selectType.getValue();
            } else {
                this.selectionFetch.selectType = 0;
            }

            //ERR ONLY
            if (this.selectErrorOnly.checked) {
                this.selectionFetch.errorOnly = true;
            }

            //KEY
            if (this.selectKeyword.getValue() != null) {
                this.selectionFetch.keyword = this.selectKeyword.getValue();
            }

            //FROM
            if (this.selectFrom.getValue() != null) {
                this.selectionFetch.from = stamp.toISOString(this.selectFrom.getValue());
            }

            //TILL
            if (this.selectTill.getValue() != null) {
                this.selectionFetch.till = stamp.toISOString(this.selectTill.getValue());
            }

            //USER
            if (this.selectUser.getValue() != null && this.selectUser.getValue() != "") {
                this.selectionFetch.user = this.selectUser.getValue();
            }

            //TYPE
//          if (this.selectType.getValue() != null && this.selectType.getValue() != "") {
//              this.selectionFetch.type = this.selectType.getValue();
//          }
//          
            this.store.fetchProperties = this.selectionFetch;

            //this.refresh();
        },

        getWindowTitle: function() {
            return this.resources.getString('servicelog.title');
        },

        exportData : function() {

            var queryStr = dojo.objectToQuery(this.selectionFetch);
            var url = "servicelog/find/export/?" + queryStr;

            FileDownloader.download(url, "Export", "GET");
        },

        /**
         * This method is called by the parent widget to get a array of functional control elements
         */
        getMenuItems: function() {
            if(this.logger.isDebug()) {
                this.logger.debug("getMenuItems()");
            }

            return [this.buttonReload]; //, this.buttonExport];
        },

        /**
         * This Method returns the params to reinit this widget with the actuall settings 
         */
        getOptions: function(){
            return { restore : this.selectionFetch };
        },

        setOptions: function(options) {
            if(this.logger.isDebug()) {
                this.logger.debug("setOptions(options: ", options ,")");
            }

            if (!options || options == null) {
                return false;
            }

            this.selectionFetch = options;

            console.debug("setOptions", this.selectionFetch);

            //SELECT TYPE
            if (this.selectionFetch.selectType) {
                console.debug("set selectType to: ", this.selectionFetch.selectType);
                this.selectType.setValue('item', { nr : this.selectionFetch.selectType });
            } else {
                console.debug("set selectType to all");
                this.selectType.setValue('item', { nr : 0 });
            }

            //ERR ONLY
            if (this.selectionFetch.errorOnly && this.selectionFetch.errorOnly == true) {
                this.selectErrorOnly.set('checked', true);
            }

            //KEY
            if (this.selectionFetch.keyword) {
                this.selectKeyword.setValue(this.selectionFetch.keyword);
            }

            //FROM
            if (this.selectionFetch.from) {
                this.selectFrom.setValue(stamp.fromISOString(this.selectionFetch.from));
            }

            //TILL
            if (this.selectionFetch.till) {
                this.selectTill.setValue(stamp.fromISOString(this.selectionFetch.till));
            }

            //USER
            if (this.selectionFetch.user) {
                this.selectUser.setValue(this.selectionFetch.user);
            }

            return true;
        },

        openDetailWidget: function(args, newWindow) {
            if(this.logger.isDebug()) {
                this.logger.debug('openDetailWidget: function(args,newWindow): ', args ,',', newWindow);
            }

            this.openContentWidget(ServiceLogDetailWidget, args, newWindow);
        },

        /**
         * This method converts the backend-side view object array to a valid grid structure
         */
        prepareColumnStructure: function() {

            if(this.logger.isDebug()) {
                this.logger.debug("prepareColumnStructure(datafieldDataList: ", datafieldDataList ,")");
            }

            /* Parts of struture: scroll & no scroll */
            var cells = {scroll: true, cells: new Array(6) }; 

            /* the first column */
            cells.cells[0] = {
                    field        : 'logId',
                    name         : this.resources.getString('servicelog.grid.id'),  
                    width        : '60px',
                    headerStyles : 'height: '+ this.HEADER_HEIGHT +'px; white-space: normal;',
                    formatter    : Formatter.stringFormat
            };

            cells.cells[1] = {
                    field        : 'requestAt',
                    name         : this.resources.getString('servicelog.grid.request_at'),
                    width        : '120px',
                    headerStyles : 'height: '+ this.HEADER_HEIGHT +'px; white-space: normal;',
                    formatter    : Formatter.dateTimeFormat
            };

            cells.cells[2] = {
                    field        : 'serviceType',
                    name         : this.resources.getString('servicelog.grid.type'),
                    width        : '120px',
                    headerStyles : 'height: '+ this.HEADER_HEIGHT +'px; white-space: normal;',
                    formatter    : Formatter.stringFormat,
                    get          : lang.hitch(this, function(rowId, obj) {
                        if(obj && obj != null){
                            return this.resources.getString('servicelog.type.' + obj.serviceType);
                        }
                    })
            };

            cells.cells[3] = {
                    field        : 'requestUser',
                    name         : this.resources.getString('servicelog.grid.user'),
                    width        : '120px',
                    headerStyles : 'height: '+ this.HEADER_HEIGHT +'px; white-space: normal;',
                    formatter    : Formatter.stringFormat
            };

            cells.cells[4] = {
                    field        : 'responseAt',
                    name         : this.resources.getString('servicelog.grid.worktime'),
                    width        : '120px',
                    headerStyles : 'height: '+ this.HEADER_HEIGHT +'px; white-space: normal;',
                    get          : lang.hitch(this, function(rowId, obj) {
                        if(obj && obj != null){

                            var from = stamp.fromISOString(obj.requestAt);
                            var till = stamp.fromISOString(obj.responseAt);

                            if ((till - from) < 0) return '-'; 

                            return number.round((till - from) / 1000) + ' sec';
                        }
                    })
            };

            cells.cells[5] = {
                    field        : 'errorCode',
                    name         : this.resources.getString('servicelog.grid.error'),
                    width        : '150px',
                    headerStyles : 'height: '+ this.HEADER_HEIGHT +'px; white-space: normal;',
                    formatter    : Formatter.stringFormat,
                    get          : lang.hitch(this, function(rowId, obj) {
                        if(obj && obj != null){
                            return this.resources.getString('servicelog.error.' + obj.errorCode);
                        }
                    })
            };

            return [ cells ];
        },
```